# jOOQ how to extract a value from a Field

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I'm joining some tables from jOOQ and I'd like to use a `RecordMapper` to parse the result into my pojo `AType`.

```
final List<AType> typeList = dsl.select()
                .from(TABLEA)
                .join(TABLEB).on(TABLEA.ID.equal(TABLEB.ID))
                .fetch()
                .map((RecordMapper<Record, AType>) record -> {
                     //Extract field values from Record
                     return  new AType(....);
                });
```

As I explained in a comment, I would like to know how to convert a `Field` object from the `Record` into the contained value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The method you're looking for is [`Record.getValue(Field)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Record.html#getValue-org.jooq.Field-) (or also `Record.get(Field)` from jOOQ 3.8 onwards):

```
.map((RecordMapper<Record, AType>) record -> {
     //Extract field values from Record
     return new AType(record.getValue(TABLEA.ID), ...);
});
```